# Allow OWIN to redirect my angularjs virtual path when refreshing

Tags: angularjs, http-status-code-404, owin

I'm currently debugging in visual studio and so my site is being hosted by IIS express.

In my app, if I go to /login via angular, it works fine and loads my partial page. If I refresh the page however, I get a 404 error. Even when trying to set up an app.Map to modify my route back to index.cshtml, it's not working.

```
    app.Map("/login", (map) =>
    {
        map.Use(
            async (context, next) =>
            {
                //...
            });
    });
```

The response code is fine, with 200, but IIS is still giving a 404 error.

My ultimate goal is to be able to save the state of my ui-router path so I can bookmark it and come back to it, with the server redirecting back to my angular application and the application navigating to the proper state.

How on earth do I accomplish this? I don't want to have to do any IIS configurations, because I might not even use IIS.

Another option I would think to use would be to have the server send back a hash url, like /#/login, but it doesn't seem to allow that. OWIN seems to always parse the hash as %23 and I can't seem to bypass it.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://coderwall.com/p/mycbiq/deep-linking-angularjs-on-windows-azure-iis

Comment: That works. I saw another post somewhere about that, but it made it out that IIS had to be configured some way. Does this work if I'm not running on IIS too? Could you make that as an answer?

Comment: I'm not sure. My guess is it will only work with IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your web.config. This is the rewrite module in IIS:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[Source](https://coderwall.com/p/mycbiq/deep-linking-angularjs-on-windows-azure-iis)

Comment: This is a good, working answer. I'm going to wait and see what other ideas people have before choosing, but right now this works for my current situation. I was hoping there was a pure OWIN solution, but maybe there's not.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved purely in OWIN by using a middleware to rewrite the requests.

```
public async override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
{           
    if(!Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
    {
        context.Request.Path = new PathString("/");
    }
    await _next.Invoke(context);
}
```

Note that if you are also running WebAPI endpoints in the same application then you may need to exclude their paths from being rewritten.